Can I create a local S3 bucket using AWS SAM, upload a file to it and read it using a python script
Here is my template.yaml file and the python script that I'm running.
template.yaml
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Transform: AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31
Description: An example SAM template for a Python Lambda function

Resources:
  MyS3Bucket:
    Type: AWS::S3::Bucket
    Properties:
      BucketName: MyS3Bucket
  LambdaFunction:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      Handler: lambda_function.lambda_handler
      Runtime: python3.9
      Timeout: 10
      Policies:
        - S3ReadPolicy:
            BucketName: !Ref MyS3Bucket
        - S3WritePolicy:
            BucketName: !Ref MyS3Bucket
      Environment:
        Variables:
          S3_BUCKET: !Ref MyS3Bucket

Outputs:
  LambdaFunctionArn:
    Description: "ARN of the Lambda Function"
    Value: !GetAtt LambdaFunction.Arn

lambda_function.py
import boto3

s3 = boto3.client('s3')

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    # Upload a file to S3 bucket
    file_content = b"Your file content here"
    s3.put_object(Bucket='MyS3Bucket', Key='example.txt', Body=file_content)
    
    return {
        'statusCode': 200,
        'body': 'File uploaded successfully!'
    }

I use sam local start-lambda to start the SAM and use sam local invoke LambdaFunction to invoke the lambda.
But this throws an error "An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the PutObject operation: Access Denied".
Can I create S3 bucket only using SAM and upload a file to that S3 bucket.
I don't need to use a 3rd party app like localstack to do this.
What are the workaround. Please help.
I use sam local start-lambda to start the SAM and use sam local invoke LambdaFunction to invoke the lambda.
But this throws an error {"errorMessage": "An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the PutObject operation: Access Denied", "errorType": "ClientError", "requestId": "ef7b2bfe-688a-4f77-8a0c-867887f9c2ee", "stackTrace": ["  File \"/var/task/lambda_function.py\", line 8, in lambda_handler\n    s3.put_object(Bucket='MyS3Bucket', Key='example.txt', Body=file_content)\n", "  File \"/var/runtime/botocore/client.py\", line 553, in _api_call\n    return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)\n", "  File \"/var/runtime/botocore/client.py\", line 1009, in _make_api_call\n    raise error_class(parsed_response, operation_name)\n"]}.

Yes, you can create an S3 bucket with AWS SAM only. AWS SAM is an extension to CloudFormation and provides short-hand syntax for serverless resources.
But your S3 bucket name MyS3Bucket is not valid. It must not contain upper-case letters.
See the full list of S3 bucket naming rules.
Simply deploy the AWS SAM template and it will deploy it similar to CloudFormation.
You are assigning S3ReadPolicy to the Lambda Function only. Hence, the function is missing the permission s3:PutObject .
Add S3WritePolicy also: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/serverless-policy-template-list.html#s3-write-policy

Sorry, my bad. I have updated the question. However, adding S3WritePolicy did not change the error message it is still there.

I don't need to deploy this on AWS. need to run locally.
added this to template.yaml
  S3WritePolicy:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Policy
    Properties:
      PolicyName: S3WritePolicy
      Roles:
        - !GetAtt LambdaFunctionRole.Arn
      PolicyDocument:
        Version: '2012-10-17'
        Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Action:
              - s3:PutObject
              - s3:PutObjectAcl
              - s3:PutLifecycleConfiguration
            Resource: 
              - arn:aws:s3:::mybucket/*
              - arn:aws:s3:::mybucket


@Hansamal may I ask why you are using AWS when you don't want to deploy it? I also updated my answer because there is an error in your template.

As a team, we need to do smoke testing locally as far as possible. We are trying to replicate all possible services locally. So we just need to run services locally and do smoke testing. That's why we don't need to deploy.
